# How can I make an iteration then iterate the same object again after a break in Blade PHP (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In my controller, I'm passing a `Collection` of 8 items:

```
$data['items'] = Item::orderBy('id','desc')->take(8)->get();
```

to the view. Using Blade, I want to break the collection in half and render each half in different positions:

```php
@foreach($items as $item)
  // iterate "n" times (4 for example)
@endforeach

// some html...

@foreach($items as $item)
  // iterate the rest 4 items from the same object $items
@endforeach
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Slice](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-slice) your `$items` collection in half:

```php
// Slice collection from the 0 index for a length of 4 (the first 4 items)
@foreach($items->slice(0, 4) as $item)
  // ...
@endforeach

// Iterate over the rest from th 4 index. 
// By passing the second parameter you can restrain the length.
@foreach($items->slice(4) as $item)
  // ...
@endforeach
```

Or [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-chunk) it into two collections.

Comment: This works for me!.... The another method (chunk) gave me an error (undefined index offset 1) using the answer bellow. Thanks pal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use The [split method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-split) to break a collection into the given number of groups:

Example:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);

$groups = $collection->split(2);

$groups->toArray(); // [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

In your controller:

```
$data['items'] = Item::orderBy('id','desc')->take(8)->get()->split(2);
```

Blade:

```
@foreach($items[0] as $item)
    // iterate "n" times (4 for example)
@endforeach

// some html...

@foreach($items[1] as $item)
    // iterate the rest 4 items from the same object $items
@endforeach
```

Comment: I believe this is a better solution than mine and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @ErnestoFlames, just remove `toArray` method and it should work

Answer (score 1):

[See the Chunk() method:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-chunk)

> The chunk method breaks the collection into multiple, smaller
>   collections of a given size:
>
> ```
> $collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);
>
> $chunks = $collection->chunk(4);
>
> $chunks->toArray();
>
> // [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
> ```
>
> This method is especially useful in views when working with a grid
>   system such as Bootstrap. Imagine you have a collection of Eloquent
>   models you want to display in a grid:
>
> ```
> @foreach ($products->chunk(3) as $chunk)
>     <div class="row">
>         @foreach ($chunk as $product)
>             <div class="col-xs-4">{{ $product->name }}</div>
>         @endforeach
>     </div>
> @endforeach
> ```

In your specific situation, you can do this:

```
@foreach($items->chunk(4)->toArray[1] as $item)
  //iterate "n" times (4 for example)
@endforeach

some <html>

@foreach($items->chunk(4)->toArray[2] as $item)
  //iterate the rest 4 items from the same object $items
@endforeach
```